# Question wrongly closed as duplicate

Tags: support, closed-questions

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115565/stability-of-beta-and-daily-live) comparing the beta and daily-live builds of Ubuntu+1, was closed as an exact duplicate of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36259/are-daily-builds-of-ubuntu-stable-enough-for-general-desktop-usage), which is a much more general question, "Are daily builds of Ubuntu stable enough for general desktop usage?"

I had asked 3 specific questions (numbered 1,2,3) which only compare beta and daily-live with each other, given that I'm using a pre-release version. They do not ask if I should use a pre-release version to begin with. Therefore I think this was incorrectly closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Please do not ask multiple questions in one post. It kind of defeats the purpose of the Q&A format.

If possible, I imagine it would be more correct to close your question as a duplicate to several questions. Unfortunately, StackExchange's close reason system isn't as expressive as some of us would like.

Your first two questions were really duplicates of:

- [Are daily builds of Ubuntu stable enough for general desktop usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36259/are-daily-builds-of-ubuntu-stable-enough-for-general-desktop-usage)
- [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-if-i-keep-upgrading)

And the third is too localized, because it solicits advice on the current state of Ubuntu's pre-releases. This will not be useful to future visitors to the site. Perhaps ask a new, more general question "What is the difference between Beta and Daily releases"? Or, if you want specific advice on 12.04 beta, try the Ubuntu forums.

If you're wondering why we do things this way, read [*The Wikipedia of Long Tail Answers*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). That's what SE sites like AskUbuntu aim to be.

Comment: You can manually edit and add the duplicate links of the other relevant questions if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The senior signatories of the flag and closure considered this carefully - in that this question covered the *same ground* as the linked question and as such should either be *closed or merged* with the question.

From my point of view, a beta is simply a point in time towards the stable release.  The daily builds are again, just points in time.

Thus in terms of the question asked, the stability of a beta and daily are similar.  Many of the answers in the linked question considered the same points.

Remember, questions can be reopened.

1. Consider carefully if the question needs to be reworded.
2. With sufficient rep - you will be able to nominate a question to be reopened.
3. You can always pop into the Ubuntu Regulators chat room and with the help of those that have sufficient rep can reopen questions.
4. Consider raising a bounty on the linked question indicating what additional information you require that is not already covered by the current answers.

Comment: You know that "a beta is simply a point in time towards the stable release. The daily builds are again, just points in time." This seems to answer the 3 questions I had. However, I did not have this knowledge, which is why I asked the question to begin with. As far as I knew, betas might have been special, but now I know they're not. The comparison between betas and daily-live does not seem to be covered in the linked question. In any case, closed or not, I seem to have the answer to my questions. :-)